# Elastic Beanstalk Health Degraded

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

I am trying to to deploy an Node.js Docker image to Elastic Beanstalk using Travis CI.  The tests and builds in Travis keep passing and successfully deploying however, I keep getting the following warn and error on my Elastic Beanstalk console

> WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Info to Degraded. Incorrect application 
>       version found on all instances. Expected version "Sample Application" (deployment 1). 
>       Application update failed 31 seconds ago and took 15 minutes.
>
> ERROR: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application 
>       version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate 
>       application version.

I am using the free tier so I am not sure if that's the issue or what exactly I am doing wrong. Below is what my .travis.yml file looks like:

```
  sudo: required
services:
- docker
before_install:
- docker build -t poolafrica/pool_auth -f Dockerfile.dev .
script:
- docker run poolafrica/pool_auth npm run test -- --coverage

deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  edge: true
  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_ID
  secret_access_key:
    secure: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
  region: eu-west-2
  app: pool_auth
  env: PoolAuth-env
  bucket_name: elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-2-747115545713
  on:
    branch: master

  skip_cleanup: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and the cause was the command timeout

**Default max deployment time -Command timeout- is 600 (10 minutes)**

Go to Your Environment →  Configuration → Deployment preferences → Command timeout

Increase the Deployment preferences for example 1800

or upgrade the instance type to work faster

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me the fix was bad formatting in an nginx conf file.

I changed 
`listen: 3000;`
to 
`listen 3000;`.

It was a case of searching through the log files to find the cause of the issue. Very time consuming, but a good learning experience!